# How to inspect the flow of events with Firebug (or something like that)?

Tags: debugging, events, firebug

I'm facing an issue with inputs loosing focus. The issue is like this:

1. I send an AJAX request to load a form, when loaded I display it with in a modal.
2. Now if I click on any of the inputs it gains focus and blurs immediately, so I need to click it again (and this time it stays focused).

I need a tool that traces the event flow and dispatching in Firebug's console (or some similar tool), so that I can detect the culprit for this odd behavior and fix it.

I have tried Eventbug and FireQuery; but I haven't be able to find the code that causes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may go to scripts panel of Firebug, then hover your mouse over the input, then click <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> from the keyboard to activate "Break on next", then click the input, and it should hit a breakpoint in the onclick handler of the input, then you can go through the code to find potential calls that cause blur (provided that you don't do any aggressive polling via `setInterval`/`setTimeout` in your javascript for some reason, or the framework you use doesn't; then it'll likely pause in that code).

You may also want to execute some code at the very beginning of the page to override the `addEventListener` method so that you hijack it: log any calls to it, and forward execution to the original function; see slides 13-14 of [my presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/jakubg/userscripts-augmenting-and-automating-web-browsing-and-debugging) (I do it in Greasemonkey, but it's not relevant here; just make sure this is executed at the very beginning of the page).

Comment: The Alt+Ctrl+B didn't work cause there seems to be several firing-of-events. I will try the addEventListener method hijack and report back. I use Greasemonkey so I could even register your Userscript for my development URL.

Comment: I've used a modified Userscript and this has helped me a lot. I still need to catch the source of the bug, but this is definitely the way to go.